# Yajra No available engine for App\User

Tags: laravel, yajra-datatable

I've made for my cms admins role 
now i have 2 admin roles super admin and normal admin 
i have a page that manage users both super admin and normal admin can see it but with different data

here's the controller code

```
  public function index()
    {        
         $this->super_admin_role_check();
        return view('admin.users.index');   
    }



    public function usersList(){
        $super_admin_role = Role::where('name','super_admin')->first();
        $is_super_admin=$this->isSuperAdmin();

        if($is_super_admin){
            $data = User::all();
        }else{
            // Admin can get all users except super admin
            $super_admin = DB::table('role_user')->where('role_id',$super_admin_role->id)->first();
            $data = User::where('id','!=',$super_admin->user_id)->first();
        }

        if(!$data){
            $data=[];
        }
        return DataTables::of($data)->make(true);
    }   




    // This function check if the super_admin roles exist or not
    public function super_admin_role_check(){

        $user = Auth::guard()->user();

        $super_admin_role = Role::where('name','super_admin')->first();

        if(!$super_admin_role){

            \Artisan::call('db:seed'); 

            // if there's no role factory create super_admin role and assign it to the super admin user
            $super_admin_role = Role::where('name','super_admin')->first();

            DB::table('role_user')->insert([
            'user_id'=>$user->id,'role_id'=>$super_admin_role->id
            ]);

            $permissions = Permission::all();

            // here i give all permissions to the super admin
            foreach($permissions as $permission){

            DB::table('permission_role')->insert(['permission_id'=>$permission->id,
            'role_id'=>$super_admin_role->id
            ]);
            }
        }
        return $super_admin_role;
    }








    // This Function Check if the user is super admin?
    public function isSuperAdmin(){
        $user = Auth::guard()->user();
        $super_admin_role = Role::where('name','super_admin')->first();
        $is_super_admin = DB::table('role_user')->where('user_id',$user->id)->where('role_id',$super_admin_role->id)->first();
        return $is_super_admin;
    }
```

The problem is that when i'm login as super admin everythings goes well but when i'm login as normal admin i get error "No available engine for App\User"
 in    \vendor\yajra\laravel-datatables-oracle\src\DataTables.php
any help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with this?

`$data = User::where('id','!=',$super_admin->user_id)->get();`

Comment: yes but when i'm dd it in the index function everything is normal

Comment: $data = User::where('id','!=',$super_admin->user_id)->get();

Answer (score 1):

Remove first(). Since you re returning only one row.

```
$data = User::where('id','!=',$super_admin->user_id);
```

This should work

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that this error comes up when working with [Yajra Laravel DataTables](https://yajrabox.com/docs/laravel-datatables/master/introduction) library, more specifically when you only retrieve a single model and pass it into the [of(...) method](https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables/blob/b00f25b1941879b34e05f270835235a32b46567c/src/DataTables.php#L33).

Below are some examples of retrieving single models in which the library will throw an error (`No available engine for App\\Models\\ModelName at project-root-path\\vendor\\yajra\\laravel-datatables-oracle\\src\\DataTables.php:63`) when the retrieved model is passed directly into the library's `DataTables::of(/* model here */)->make(true)` method.

[Retrieving Single Models / Aggregates](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#retrieving-single-models)

```php
// Retrieve a model by its primary key...
$flight = Flight::find(1);

// Retrieve the first model matching the query constraints...
$flight = Flight::where('active', 1)->first();

// Alternative to retrieving the first model matching the query constraints...
$flight = Flight::firstWhere('active', 1);
```

I got around the issue by wrapping the retrieved model in an array. i.e:

```php
$model = User::where('id','!=',$super_admin->user_id)->first();

DataTables::of($model ? [$model] : [])
            ->make(true);
```

*Side note*: Eloquent's `first()`, `find()`and `firstWhere()` methods return `null` if the model isn't found.

*Tested with*: `"yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle": "~9.0"  // Specifically v9.17.1`